# Mounting one linux machine on to another

Tags: mount

I have 2 ubuntu desktops at my work place. I want to mount the newer system, **sys2** on the old system, **sys1**.

Both the system's have cifs installed.

I can easily ssh to my new system,**sys2** from my  old system,sys1 but, I want to mount the remote machine(sys2) both via command line and also with GUI. Can you guide me with steps needed for the same.

Hope to hear from you guys.

Thanks

Comment: can you explain a little more, what you want to achieve by "mounting" them on each other?

Comment: Hi Phillip: The new system, sys2 is the much faster, 128GB ram and I would like to run my computational problems on it for the time being, before I completely transfer everything on my sys2 from sys1

Comment: so, you want to access what is on sys1:/home/youruser/ in a directory on sys2 - for example sys2:/media/youruser/sys1/ ? Do you need anything else from sys1 to run your computational problems on sys2?

Comment: sys1: local machine, sys2: remote new machine. I want to have full access to the sys2 machine and I think the way for that is mounting it

Comment: mounting usually refers to accessing block devices or media from your filesystem tree. i.e. /dev/sda1 (your first harddisk partition) could be mounted at /boot to hold kernel and bootloader files.
your idea on using all ressources of sys2 might be a little more complicated, but I will try to point you in some directions.

Comment: Have you considered sharing the home directory on sys1 using sambashare or the like? Then you could "mount" the network share on sys2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our short conversation below your question I think you need a combination of several techniques:

- getting your files to sys2
- remote-controlling sys2 while physically sitting in front of sys1
- optionally: sharing the workload between both systems

As getting too deep into each of these would hit the boundaries of one question, I only point you at some ressources and after that you might come back with new questions on details of them.

**getting your files to sys2**

there are various solutions to this problem:

- samba/cifs (share the folder on sys1, mount it on sys2 - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide / https://askubuntu.com/a/101037/555486
- sshfs ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS )
- nfs ( https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-file-system.html )
- syncing (as in replicating them using tools as rsync, syncthing, etc pp - please just use some search engine to find help on those)

which one you would like to use in the end is totally up to you, each has its down- and upsides. for example cifs, sshfs and nfs are slower all the time, while replicating will take some time, but calculations should afterwards be a lot faster than using a network-filesystem.

**remote-controlling sys2 while physically sitting in front of sys1**

to control a linux machine from another there are some different options as well:

- VNC/RDP/some other form of graphical remote desktop protocol
- remote shell/terminal protocols (SSH, RSH, Telnet)
- job scheduling systems (which are overkill on your two systems setup)

*VNC* - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC
*RDP* - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/xrdp
*SSH* - you already seem to know about that
*RSH/telnet* - well, stick to SSH if you not that already

**Fazit**

Well, thats mostly it: get your files to sys2 and execute the jobs there. Afterwards transfer your results back.

***Optional* workload balancing**

Depending on the type of workload you might find solutions to use both systems to do part of the jobs:

- distcc (can divide the task of compile huge programms to several machines)
- distributed computing projects at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_distributed_computing_projects (just fyi)

If I yould know more about the actual tasks you want to load onto sys2, I might be able to help you find a fitting solution to sharing the workload on both systems.