# mount cifs gives error(95)

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

We have a build system on OSX where we mount a remote volume using:

```
  mount -t smbfs //userid:pwd@srver02/TestDataFiles /Users/Shared/test
```

We are setting up an Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS system where we need to mount the same volume.
Using the command:

```
   mount -t cifs -o user=userid,pass=pwd //srver02/TestDataFiles /mnt/test
```

gives an error:

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Which isn't very helpful.  Yes, I did install the cifs-util package.
I've done a lot of searches, finding lots of suggestions for random command line changes, none of which has worked. (vers=1.0 or 2.0 or 3.0, and a few other misc options.)

Is there any way to find out exactly WHAT the command is complaining about?
The suggested dup question doesn't help, as I've already tried the various vers settings, and running as root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mount a CIFS share?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101029/how-do-i-mount-a-cifs-share)

Answer (score 0):

On my configuration, a required minimum Samba version gave me this same error and was fixed by adding:

```
vers=3.0
```

to the options list. Although this doesn't address the OP's issue, it might help someone else down the line. Also, try using the verbose (-v) switch to get more information from the client side.

Finally, if you have access, configure a more verbose log level on the server and investigate the resultant logs:
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch12.html

You can quickly find the server's log file location with the following:

```
grep "log file" /etc/samba/smb.conf
```